# Finding a element from a website with, using classname, css-selector and xpath

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm looking for some help with my code.

I'm trying to print out an element from a website, but I get different error messages from the methods I try, none of them work.

I've tried using class_name with the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver    
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/home/cena/Downloads/chromedriver')

poeisz_url = "https://webwinkel.poiesz-supermarkten.nl/boodschappen/producten/631258"
poeisz_classname = "full-product full-product--price__for"

browser.get(poeisz_url)
elem = browser.find_element_by_class_name(poeisz_classname)
print(elem.text)
```

this returned the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cena/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/scratch_2.py", line 9, in <module>
    elem = browser.find_element_by_class_name(poeisz_classname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 564, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.169)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Linux 4.15.0-50-generic x86_64)
```

So I tried using xpath and css_selector to work around it:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/home/cena/Downloads/chromedriver')

poeisz_url = "https://webwinkel.poiesz-supermarkten.nl/boodschappen/producten/631258"
poeisz_classname = "full-product full-product--price__for"

browser.get(poeisz_url)
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='" + poeisz_classname + "']")
print(elem.text)
```

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/home/cena/Downloads/chromedriver')

poeisz_url = "https://webwinkel.poiesz-supermarkten.nl/boodschappen/producten/631258"
poeisz_classname = "full-product full-product--price__for"

browser.get(poeisz_url)
elem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("*[class^='" + poeisz_classname + "']")
print(elem.text)
```

they, in order, returned these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cena/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/scratch_2.py", line 9, in <module>
    elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='" + poeisz_classname + "']")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@class='full-product full-product--price__for']"}
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.169)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Linux 4.15.0-50-generic x86_64)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cena/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/scratch_2.py", line 9, in <module>
    elem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("*[class^='" + poeisz_classname + "']")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 598, in find_element_by_css_selector
    return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[class^='full-product full-product--price__for']"}
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.169)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Linux 4.15.0-50-generic x86_64)
```

I'm quite new to programming, so I'm sorry if it's something stupid. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`WebDriverWait`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html):

for example XPath:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/cena/Downloads/chromedriver')
url = "https://webwinkel.poiesz-supermarkten.nl/boodschappen/producten/631258"
driver.get(url)
my_el = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="products"]//*[@class="full-product full-product--price__for"]')))
print(my_el.text)
```

The output is:

> 0 99

The better way to use `WebDriverWait` is to use it as a var:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
my_el = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="products"]//*[@class="full-product full-product--price__for"]')))
```

As [@DebanjanB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7429447/debanjanb) has commented you might want to use `visibility_of_element_located()` not `presence_of_element_located`.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: If you wouldn't mind me asking, why does this work? Sorry, I don't have much experience :)

Comment: the basic idea is to wait explicitly for an element... what happens is sometimes your driver runs to fast and the element is not loaded yet... this is best practice to use explicit-waits and not `sleep`...

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are running into is explained in the first error message.

> invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted

`find_element_by_class_name()` takes a *single* class name as a parameter but "full-product full-product--price__for" contains two class names (NOTE: class names are separated by spaces, so there are two here... "full-product" and "full-product--price__for".

You can instead convert your locator into a CSS selector, `.full-product.full-product--price__for`, and it should work just fine.

To read more about CSS selectors, see the links below.

[Selenium Tips: CSS Selectors](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors)
[WC3 reference, Selectors Level 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#overview)
[Taming Advanced CSS Selectors](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/taming-advanced-css-selectors/)